# Fast way to convert array of points into triangle strip?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl, line, points

I have an array of CGPoints (basic struct with two floats: x and y). I want to use OpenGL ES to draw a textured curve using these points. I can do this fine with just two points, but it gets harder when I need to make a line from several points.

Currently I draw a line horizontally, calculate its angle from the points given, and then rotate it. I don't think doing this for all lines in a curve is a good idea. There's probably a faster way.

I'm thinking that I can "enlarge" or "constrict" all the points at once to make a curve with some sort of width.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive what you want to accomplish, but consider this:

Based on a ordered list of points, you can draw a polyline using those points.  If you want to have a polyline with a 2D texture on it, you can draw a series of quadrilaterals (using two triangles each, of course).  You can generate these quadrilaterals using an idea similar to catmul-rom spline generation.

Consider a series of points p[i-1], p[i], p[i+1].  Now, for each i, you can find two points each an epsilon distance away from p[i] along the line perpendicular to the line connecting p[i-1] and p[i+1]. You can determine the two points generated for the endpoints in various ways, like using the perpendicular to the line from p[0] to p[1].

I'm not sure if this will be faster than your method, but you should be caching the results.  If you are planning on doing this every frame, another type of solution to your problem may be needed.